# How to make an overflow element take up the remaining vertical height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space) as it seems the most relevant for what I wish to do, but it doesn't seem to work when the body element is an overflow container.

Specifically in my case I have a dynamically sized header and a body. I would like the body to take up the remaining screen height. Normally this would be trivial but the body is an overflow one, and apparently this complicates things. I've included a reproduction of the problem below:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100%;
}

.items {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      fills remaining space
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see when you run it, there are two scrollbars, where there should only be one (for `items`). Is it possible to have `content` take up the remaining screen height such that there is no document scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `overflow: auto` to the `.content` seems to fix the problem

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.items {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <div class="items">
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
        <div class="item">content item</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `flex-grow:1` and shorten your CSS rules . `overflow` set on `.content` will make `.content` scroll when needed.

```css
html,
body,
.box {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    fills remaining space
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you wanted `.items` to scroll ***(what i understood from your question)*** , flex box can be imbricated if the scroll is needed a level lower, the method is the same and `.content` will fill remain space, then `.items` will fill also remaining space inside `.content` to finally scroll when needed :

```css
html,
body,
.box {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box,
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.content {
  height: auto;
  flex-grow:1;
  background-color: #ddd;
  min-height: 0;
}

.items {
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
    <div class="header-item">header item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    fills remaining space
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
      <div class="item">content item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```